# React-boilerplate, reducer sending me a object instead of my default initialState?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga, saga, react-boilerplate

I'm not getting my initialState while ajax requests in the pending?
Here is the snapshot of both actual data and reducer initialstate.

[**this.props** of my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJrZa.png)

here is my reducercode:

```js
/*
 *
 * MainPage reducer
 *
 */
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';
import { LOAD_BANNERS, LOAD_BANNERS_SUCCESS, LOAD_BANNERS_ERROR, LOAD_CAROUSELS, LOAD_CAROUSELS_SUCCESS, LOAD_CAROUSELS_ERROR, LOAD_SIDEBAR, LOAD_SIDEBAR_SUCCESS, LOAD_SIDEBAR_ERROR } from './constants';

export const initialState = fromJS({
  bannerItems: [],
  carouselItems: [],
  sidebarItems: [],
  loadingBanners: false,
  errorBanners: true,
  loadingCarousels: false,
  errorCarousels: true,
  loadingSidebar: false,
  errorSidebar: true
});

function mainPageReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOAD_BANNERS:
      return state.set('loadingBanners', true).set('errorBanners', false);
    case LOAD_BANNERS_SUCCESS:
      return state.set('loadingBanners', false).set('errorBanners', false).set('bannerItems', action.bannerItems);
    case LOAD_BANNERS_ERROR:
      return state.set('loadingBanners', false).set('errorBanners', action.error);
    case LOAD_CAROUSELS:
      return state.set('loadingCarousels', true).set('errorCarousels', false);
    case LOAD_CAROUSELS_SUCCESS:
      return state.set('loadingCarousels', false).set('errorCarousels', false).set('carouselItems', action.carouselItems);
    case LOAD_CAROUSELS_ERROR:
      return state.set('loadingCarousels', false).set('errorCarousels', action.error);
    case LOAD_SIDEBAR:
      return state.set('loadingSidebars', true).set('errorSidebar', false);
    case LOAD_SIDEBAR_SUCCESS:
      return state.set('loadingSidebars', false).set('errorSidebar', false).set('sidebarItems', action.sidebarItems);
    case LOAD_SIDEBAR_ERROR:
      return state.set('loadingSidebars', false).set('errorSidebar', action.error);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default mainPageReducer;
```

Why reducer sending me an object(List) instead of my initialstate.
here is code of my app.js where I have bind my dataTypes:

```js
MainPage.propTypes = {
  // dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  bannerItems: PropTypes.array,
  bannerItemsLoading: PropTypes.bool,
  carouselItems: PropTypes.array,
  carouselItemsLoading: PropTypes.bool,
  sidebarItems: PropTypes.array,
  sidebarItemsLoading: PropTypes.bool,
  loadBanners: PropTypes.func,
  loadCarousels: PropTypes.func,
  loadSidebars: PropTypes.func
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It is sending you an Immutable js object, try to do `.toJS()` on your `List` items, you will get back plain JavaScript object.(however it is not recommended to convert to and fro between immutablejs and plain js object, as it is a performance hit)

Comment: You maybe right but it's not the problem. I'm getting results fine but after two renderings of list(object). I don't know why it's happening?

Comment: Here is the code what it should be and what I'm getting? Initial State what I **want** = `{bannerItems: [],
  carouselItems: [],
  sidebarItems: [],
  loadingBanners: false,
  errorBanners: true,
  loadingCarousels: false,
  errorCarousels: true,
  loadingSidebar: false,
  errorSidebar: true}` What I'm getting is `List {size: 0, _origin: 0, _capacity: 0, _level: 5, _root: undefined, …}`

Comment: @kropani, you are getting immutable object as initialState, because of use of `fromJS` in export const initialState = fromJS({.....}). Remove this `fromJS` and you will start getting plain js object.

Comment: Dear @Rohit Garg, Is there any solution, I can't remove formJS in mycode...

Comment: @kropani, what solution you want ?

Comment: I want my **initialState** as default state from **reducer** ? where can I add code that gives me my initalState back instead of rubbish _List_ (object) ? in first some rendering?